# Wt in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2015, wt

I have created my project in WtDesigner(linked to library Wt 3.3.6) and than configured it with Microsoft Visual Studio 2015. I followed steps of this tutorial with only difference that Im using Visual Studio 2015.

When I try to run my project in Visual Studio I get next errors (I have instaled boost library version 1.62.0):

```
libboost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_59.lib(error_code.obj) :error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1600' doesn't match value '1900' in main.obj
fatal error LNK1104: cannot open "libboost_date_time-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib"
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This is very good that the compiler is complaining. Make sure that you build everything with Visual Studio 2015. Including all of the dependent dlls (not just your code).

Comment: yes, I did that

Comment: From your output: libboost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_59.lib was built with Visual Studio 2010. This file can not be part of your build.

Comment: so to solve it I should change my boost library and build it for Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Yes make sure boost and all other 3rd party libraries were compiled with Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Also the error indicates that the build is using boost 1.59 not 1.62.